# Why is this code writing only last record in file?

Tags: python

So here is the code, it's in loop but storing very last record only:

```
try:
    with open('records.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        for url in urls:
            if url.strip() != '':
                print('Processing URL:- '+url)
                data = fetch_data(url)
                csv_file.write(data)
                status = 'OK'
        csv_file.close()
except Exception,e:
    status = 'FAIL'
    print str(e)
finally:
    with open('process.log', 'a') as the_file:
        ts = time.strftime("%H:%M")
        the_file.write(ts+'\t'+url+'\t'+status+'\n')
if driver is not None:
    driver.quit()
```

`records.csv` saves only last record

Comment: please reduces this to a standalone running program that demonstrates the behavior, then run it, and show us the (incorrect) output

Comment: you do two file writes. Which one is "storing very last record only?"

Comment: Why don't you try to just concat all the content in a variable and write once?

Comment: It's probably only processing the last record since you open it in append mode and try to read from it. edit: actually, that should throw, so I'm confused.

Comment: @AdamSmith `records.csv`. Also updated the Qs

Comment: @Volatil3 I'm not sure what `data` looks like, but you know that `csv_file.write(data)` doesn't add a newline? Is it possible that all your data has been squished onto one line?

Comment: @AdamSmith oh derp I misread

Comment: @AdamSmith Darn. Yes that was the issue. `\n` was not added hence put all in a single line. I just did and worked fine. Kind of embarrassment :/. Make an answer?

Comment: @Volatil3 don't worry, I wrote a similarly trivial question just yesterday that boiled down to a spelling error. Sometimes it just takes an extra set of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.write` does not add newlines to the file, so it's likely that it's processing everything but only writing one extra line to the file.

Some nitpicks:

- You don't need to do `csvfile.close()` since you're using a `with` block.
- You don't need to set `status="OK"` in every iteration of the loop, just once above the loop.
- It might be faster to process data separately from I/O, as @bruno suggests below.

```
datalines = []
for url in urls:
    if url.strip():
        datalines.append(fetch_data(url))
csvfile.write("\n".join(datalines))
```

Comment: What's the use of introducing list while it could be saved directly in file?

Comment: @Volatil3 memory is cheap, file I/O is expensive. Writing it in-memory to the list, composing a string, then writing to file *once* is faster (probably *much* faster) than the way you're doing it. There's nothing wrong with doing a file write every loop, but it's definitely much slower.

Comment: The only issue is, if things break in middle, I'd have to start it from beginning  since I am parsing data from URLs.

Comment: the only thing that can break is `fetch_data`, so maybe wrap *that* in a `try` block?

Comment: "memory is cheap, file I/O is expensive"  : IO are buffered and the buffering takes care of available memory. When dealing with huge datasets and/or parallelisation, you may find out that IO are safer than memory...

Comment: "memory is cheap and safe, IO is expensive and safer." Better @brunodesthuilliers ? :)

Comment: Actually, as soon as you get into parallelisation, memory is not safe, and not that cheap either. Betting your ass on memory is ok when you know it's a use-once-in-a-while script working on not-too-huge datasets, but it's definitly not a wise choice for library code that might have to deal with large datasets. FWIW I'm currently having problems with some library code that was written by someone thinking that memory was "cheap and safe"...